# Como chamar uma ACTION de uma CONTROLLER específica através de um Button?

Tags: cakephp

Utilizando o o seguinte código:

```
    $this->Html->link(
          'Meus Dados', array(
                   'controller' => 'Groups', 
                   'action' => 'index'
           )
     );
```

O link HTML é criado normalmente, porém se eu quiser colocar um BUTTON no lugar do LINK, para fazer com que ao clicar no mesmo ele seja redirecionado para uma ACTION específica de uma CONTROLLER, não funciona.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
    echo $this->Form->button(
        'Meus Dados', array(
             'label' => '', 
             'style' => 'width: 100%, color: lightslategray', 
             'class' => 'topnav input-append fa fa-twitter fa-fw', 
             'url' => array(
                      'controller' => 'Groups', 
                      'action' => 'index')
         )
    );
```

Mas não acontece nada ao clicar no botão, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL da página tem que ser no `FORM` e não no `BUTTON`

```
echo $this->Form->create($row, [
    'url' => [
        'controller' => 'Groups',
        'action' => 'index'
        ]
    ]);


    echo this->Form->button('Enviar');

echo $this->Form->end();
```

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso que eu queria @jeferson-assis !!